# react-native app showing 'Unknown' on screen.?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run my react-native app, for android platform, I am getting this screen when app is loaded.

[image]

Comment: How are you running it? Have you been able to run it before?

Comment: @JRK earlier I was getting some load issue on the same screen.

Comment: Provide means to reproduce the code ,may be a expo snack?

Answer (score 1):

i faced same issue while upgrade my project it happend babel

to solve this issue install this babel for all react native projects

```
npm i metro-react-native-babel-preset --save-dev
```

then i deleted .bablerc and babel.config.js

then i manually created  babel.config.js at root directory

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  };
```

then i started window one

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

in my second window

```
react-native run-android
```

thats it

Note:after that error may be rise from other dependency(just google it)